# Angular Materials Update, Importing modules Error

Tags: angular, angular-material, webstorm

Yay for the new Angular Materials update but it broke some things I can't fix.

I did all of the things in the Changelog, and I can even compile but in my code I am getting a red squiggly under Mat'something'Module as it says "MyPATH/node_module/angular/material/**material** has no exported member 'Mat'something'module.

Notice the second material directory it appends to the path. Anybody know why this might be happening?[image]

Comment: looks as if you are still using old material version. Ctrl+click on `material` in import statement - what file is opened? Do you see the `Mat` modules there, or modules with `Md` prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for your Angular Material version you have to import Material components using `MdSomethingModule`, for example `MdDialogModule`. You can see, that new docs says us to import this:

[image]

But if you're using a previous version of Angular Material, you have to import it like this:

```
import {MdDialogModule} from '@angular/material';
```

If you're not sure, what version you are using and which way is correct, you can simply try both, one of them should work.